# GCP traffic on pod being routed to internet via VMs IP address, not cloud NAT

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a gke cluster, I've setup cloud NAT and set  `All subnets' primary and secondary IP ranges` for the cluster VPC.

But when I go to `www.ifconfig.me`, it shows me the IP address of the VM the pod is running on.

Any idea how I get traffic to route to my cloud NAT address?

Comment: Remove the Node public IPs if you want to force the traffic to use your Cloud NAT. If you keep your node public IPs, Cloud NAT will be never used.

Answer (score 0):

Check your node, it should be having a public IP. Remove that Public IP from your node to direct traffic from Cloud NAT.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

By using this [document](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/gke-example) you are able to send traffic to cloud NAT and while creating a private cluster, using cloud NAT ensures that you clear the “Access master using its external IP address” checkbox, otherwise it will take cluster IP not Cloud NAT IP.

For creating the private cluster, go to Cloud Console → click Kubernetes clusters→ create cluster -->location (zone) → click networking → select Private cluster → Clear the Access master using its external IP address checkbox → Enter a Master IP -->select the Network→ click Create.

Hope this information may help you.